# How to make call to DLL function from Delphi?

Tags: delphi, dll

```
// Get a list of accounts in a domain separated by \x00 and ended by \x00\x00
Function GetUserList(AName: PAnsiChar; Var List; Size: Longint): Longint; StdCall;
```

I need to call the above from XE6.

Would someone be kind enough to post an example of how I can
get this buffer, and put it to a stream or a string.

The variable "List" is supposed to fill up some buffer, which I can read
off the list of users.

After trying for a couple of options, I have tried all options such as:

thanks!

```
var
  Buffer: array of Byte;
  iCount : Integer;
  sName : AnsiString;
begin
  ...
  SetLength(Buffer, 4096);
  iCount := GetUserListTest(PAnsiChar(sName)@Buffer[0], Length(Buffer)); // cannot
  // iCount := GetUserList(PAnsiChar(sName), Buffer, Length(Buffer));
```

Comment: You need to know the precise details of the contract that this function adheres to. Without that knowledge you can only guess. You'll want to read the documentation to find that our.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a Win32 API function, so it must be a third-party function.  Ask the vendor for an example.

A `var` parameter expects you to pass a variable to it.  The `var` receives the address of the variable.  `@Buffer[0]` does not satisfy that requirement, as `@` returns a Pointer, and then the `var` ends up with the address of the pointer itself, not the address of the variable being pointed at.  The function is expecting a pointer to a buffer.  By using a `var` to receive that pointer, you need to drop the `@` and pass the first array element, so that the address of that element (effectively the address of the buffer) will be passed to the function, eg:

```
iCount := GetUserList(PAnsiChar(sName), Buffer[0], iCount);
```

Alternatively, you can use this syntax instead, which will pass the same address of the first element:

```
iCount := GetUserList(PAnsiChar(sName), PByte(Buffer)^, iCount);
```

Now, with that said, chances are that the function **may** allow you to query it for the necessary array size so you can allocate only what is actually needed (but check the documentation to be sure, I'm making an assumption here since you have not said otherwise)), eg:

```
procedure GetDomainUsers(const Domain: AnsiString; Users: TStrings);
var
  Buffer: array of AnsiChar;
  iCount : Integer;
  User: PAnsiChar;
begin
  // this call ASSUMES the function returns the needed
  // bytecount when given a NULL/empty array - check
  // the documentation!!!
  iCount := GetUserList(PAnsiChar(Domain), PAnsiChar(nil)^, 0);
  if iCount > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(Buffer, iCount);
    iCount := GetUserList(PAnsiChar(Domain), Buffer[0]{or: PAnsiChar(Buffer)^}, iCount);
  end;
  if iCount > 0 then
  begin
    Users.BeginUpdate;
    try
      User := PAnsiChar(Buffer);
      while User^ <> #0 do
      begin
        Users.Add(User);
        Inc(User, StrLen(User)+1);
      end;
    finally
      Users.EndUpdate;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

If that does not work, then you will have to pre-allocate a large array:

```
procedure GetDomainUsers(const Domain: AnsiString; Users: TStrings);
var
  Buffer: array of AnsiChar;
  User: PAnsiChar;
begin
  SetLength(Buffer, 1024);
  if GetUserList(PAnsiChar(Domain), Buffer[0]{or: PAnsiChar(Buffer)^}, Length(Buffer)) > 0 then
  begin
    Users.BeginUpdate;
    try
      User := PAnsiChar(Buffer);
      while User^ <> #0 do
      begin
        Users.Add(User);
        Inc(User, StrLen(User)+1);
      end;
    finally
      Users.EndUpdate;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hi Remy,

Thanks a lot for the code sample.  I realised there is indeed a GetUserCount function. No support for this API.

The function GetUserList doesn't crash now, although the strings doesn't get filled yet.  I'm thinking this must have something to do with the "separated by \x00 and ended by \x00\x00".


I tried replacing #0 with #00 or #0#0 but the TStrings still doesn't seem to get filled.

Is there a way to simply assign the array to a TStrings.Text seems there's already a separator in the array buffer returned?  Or a way to read what's in the array returned?

Comment: ...continued due to limit in posting
    // Get total number of accounts
    Function GetUserCount(aName: PAnsiChar): Longint; StdCall;

    // Get a list of accounts separated by \x00 and ended by \x00\x00
    Function GetUserList(aName: PAnsiChar; Var List; Size: Longint): Longint; StdCall;


    iUserCount := GetUserList(PAnsiChar(Domain), PAnsiChar(nil)^, 0);
    if iUserCount > 0 then
    begin
      SetLength(Buffer, iUserCount);
      //iCount := GetUserList(PAnsiChar(Domain), Buffer[0], iCount);
      iCount := GetUserList(PAnsiChar(Domain), PAnsiChar(Buffer)^, iUserCount);
    end;

Comment: What value does `GetUserList()` actually return? Is it an error value or a success value? I assume it returns a byte count, but you have not said yet. `GetUserCount()` does not help you know how many bytes to allocate for the array. You cannot pass the array as-is to `TStringList`, you have to iterate through the array, which the code I gave you does. A null-terminated double-null-terminated format is not uncommon in API programming. You need to find out why the array is not being filled, most likely the function is failing with an error.

Comment: It returned a -3.  I suppose it's -$03?

Can I simply allocate a large enough bytes
for array, and simply depend on the \x00 and
\x00\x00 to know when to stop?

If so, can you give me a code example?  I'm sorry
to trouble you.  I tried reading up for hours, but 
all the ansichar stuff is confusing. :(

  { Function Result Codes }
  S_OK = $00;

  E_FAILURE = -$01;
  E_LICENSE = -$02;
  E_PARAMS = -$03;
  E_PATH = -$04;
  E_CONFIG = -$05;

Comment: The function is failing with an `E_PARAMS` error (on which call - the first or the second? I assume the first. It probably does not like the `nil`). **Read the documentation** to find out what parameters are acceptable to it. I can't answer your question about allocating a large array, since I don't know what the function is expecting. **Read the documentation**.

Comment: As for the rest, the code example I gave you iterates the array the same way regardless of how the buffer is allocated. Yes, you can depend on the `\x00\x00` to know when to stop iterating, that is the whole point of having the data be double null terminated. But you need to focus on getting the function to fill the array without error first. Also, does the function return the names using 8bit or 16bit characters? It makes a big difference.

Comment: You are using the [VisNetic MailServer API](http://www.deerfield.net/support/VisNetic-MailServer/documentation/VisNetic_MailServer_Administrator's_Guide.pdf)? If so, did you see this comment in the documentation? "**The API.DLL can be found in the VisNetic MailServer directory and is used by the Users.exe command line tool. The source code for Users.exe can be found in the API directory and is written in Delphi.**"  Did you look at that source code for examples yet?

Comment: hi Remy, it's the icewarp mailserver. their version of the API has changed dramatically. this is an old version.  The API failed at the second call (first call, I changed to GetUserCount so it returned the number of users perfectly).   There's no documentation on the API for that old version.  Nevertheless, thank you so much for spending time to help me. :)

Comment: Remy, I just realised you posted an alternative solution. It works like a charm! Thank you so much for your patience and not giving up despite the lack of doumentation! :)  Much appreciated. :)